# Where should I set the references on a multiple-project solution?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, reference

I have two projects on a Visual Studio 2010 solution:

1- A .dll class library called DATA which has a .edmx Entity Framework Model which was created using the wizard and based on the schema of a MYSQL database file.

2- A Windows Forms project which is the User interface and just have the minimum information to sent and receive data to the .dll, which in turn will do the same against the database. This project have a reference to the first one.

The thing is that if I set the connection string on the app.config file of the .dll then when I run my app, it says to me that doesnt find the connection. So I have to set the connection string on the FORM project, which I dont like since Im trying to achieve a minimum of independence from each other.

The same happens with the mysql references... I need to set them on the FORMS project to make the app work... but this is not what I have in plans when I thought of making two separate projects, each one with its own responsibilities.

What I am thinking/doing wrong?

Comment: why is `mysql references`?

Comment: A connection string is a _dependency_ that is injected into the class library by the consumer of the library. That's exactly the way it should be. The consumer knows which database should be accessed. If you turn it around, the dll can never be used for other databases.

Comment: Thanks Arnold for your response regarding the connection string.
So what about the mysql references: Why are they needed in the Windows Form app wich solely calls procedures of the DATA .dll?